# Having issue with codeigniter multiple upload config

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-2

I have 3 type of config for my upload, the thing is when I upload the file, it uses the same config like image path for all of them and they confilict.
here is my code:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './media/content/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100000';
                $config['max_width']  = '10024';
                $config['max_height']  = '7680';
                $config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->do_upload("Image");
                $ImageData = $this->upload->data();
                $Image=$ImageData['file_name'];
                $ImageFileError=$this->upload->display_errors();
                //--------------------------
                $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config2['source_image']    = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/content/'.$Image;
                $config2['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config3['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config2['width']= 300;
                $config2['height']= 170;
                $config2['new_image']= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/content/'.'big_thumb_'.$Image;
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2); 
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                //---------------
                $config3['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config3['source_image']    = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/content/'.$Image;
                $config3['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config3['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config3['width']= 268;
                $config3['height']= 120;
                $config3['new_image']= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/content/'.'small_thumb_'.$Image;
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config3);
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config3); 
                $this->image_lib->resize();

if($_FILES['ImageHeader']['size'])
                {
                    $config8['upload_path'] = './media/content/headers/';
                    $config8['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
                    $config8['max_size']    = '100000';
                    $config8['max_width']  = '10024';
                    $config8['max_height']  = '7680';
                    $config8['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;
                    //$this->image_lib->initialize($config8);
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config8);
                    $this->upload->do_upload("ImageHeader");
                    $ImageDataHeader = $this->upload->data();
                    $ImageHeader=$ImageDataHeader['file_name'];
                    $ImageFileErrorHeader=$this->upload->display_errors();
                    $config11['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config11['source_image']   = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/content/headers/'.$ImageHeader;
                    $config11['create_thumb'] = false;
                    $config11['maintain_ratio'] = false;
                    $config11['width']= 960;
                    $config11['height']= 240;
                    //$config3['new_image']= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/region/'.'small_thumb_'.$ImageHeader;
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config11);
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config11);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                }
```

I don't know why?!!, I have uesed initilalze to use the new config, but still not working and upload all in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting `$config['upload_path'] = './media/content/';` once for the main $config and never again for the other configurations. You are also using `$config2['new_image']= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/media/content/'.'big_thumb_'.$Image;` for each of the configurations so all of the files you are creating will all be in the same folder as you stated.

You should also do the following before loading each new configuration:

```
unset($config); // Unloads the previous configuration
  $this->image_lib->clear(); // Clears the image_lib for the next configuration to be loaded
```

Then you can load your next configuration:
`$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: Make sure `$config8['upload_path'] = './media/content/headers/';` has the proper permissions and is writable.

Comment: I has the right permission 777, The thing is it uploads them to the /media/content/ folder. Very Odd! I used unset, clear() and still not working!!!